# Pandas Nth last row slice

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to slice a number of dataframes to obtain the (lets say) 5th last row of data from each df. Each of the df have varying lengths, depending of the duration sample data is taken. For example, of df is 264 rows, another is 237.

I currently can see a way to get a result using a two step process whereby the first step obtains the tail, and then I can extract the first row from there, but I figure there is likely to be a better way.

My current first step is `df = data.iloc[-5:,2:128:2]` and then I can simply remove the first row from there to give me the aggregate for the data I'm after. Any suggestions?

Comment: IIUC, just use `tail` and `reset_index()` with `iloc` `df.tail(5).reset_index(drop=True).iloc[0]` also think `df.tail(5).iloc[-5:-4]` could work too

Comment: Thanks. The second example given combined with my original code `df = data.iloc[-5:-4,2:128:2]` works. Also you've shown a couple of things I didn't know about with reset_index and also joining the different commands as in .tail(5).iloc[...] so cheers!

Comment: no problem, consdier accepting the answer by Tania so this can be closed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing in Pandas works just like in Python lists, in that you can specify a positive index (e.g. `array[0]` -> first element; `array[-1]` -> last element). If you want to extract the last row of the dataframe as a pandas.Series, you can try:

```
data.iloc[-5]
```

and if you need it as a pandas.DataFrame:

```
data.iloc[-5:-4]
```

This makes the slicing independent of the actual length of the dataframe. For more detail, see this section in the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-integer)